# Setting NSNotifications observer in a cordova plug in

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I have a cordova plugin that depends on a an accessory being connected to my iOS device. The accessory (a magnetic swiper) on notification that something is being swiped. However I not sure what I should be setting the observer as. In the example code they provide it they set it as `self` but that in a `ViewController` My plug in is not in the app controller. Any ideas?

this is the notification code that the sample code had( again this was in the `ViewController`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector:@selector(trackDataReady:)
                                             name: @"trackDataReadyNotification"
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(devConnStatusChange)
                                             name:@"devConnectionNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: by chance can someone tell me the difference when the selector has `:` at the end or not, like it is the case in this question? When not using `:` I have an error in my Cordova app because the self instance seems to not exist anymore (self is the CDVPlugin instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the object (self) is still allocated it will receive the messages when they are posted to the NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter. It does not have to be a view controller. Remember though when the object is deallocated removed the observers otherwise you will get application crashes.

Comment: That is good to know! Thank you. Issue is, It doesn't seem to be firing those notifications off! But thank you.

Comment: The Cordova plugin you are utilizing does not fire the notifications? If you need to check the notifications are firing you can always fire one off from your code in a different area to make sure they are being caught by your class.